# How to add CSS external files to be used by my R package function?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm making a personal package and would like to load a css file in one of the functions in this package in order to have a "default style". What is the optimal way of doing this?

I cannot find any documnetation that helps me understand how to work with external data like a css file, mostly what I find is about exporting external datasets to be loaded separately, etc.

Comment: I this for a shiny app or something? I think the best fit would be putting it in the `extdata` folder then you can easily access it within the pacakge: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

Comment: Yes! At first I tried putting it into the extdata folder, but was mistakenly calling it directly instead of using `system.file()`, so it wasn't working. Thanks for the doc page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using the inst/extdata folder to export my style.css file, but was trying to read it directly in the code. Thanks to @MrFlick docpage, I found out I had to use the `system.file()` function in order to use the exported file.